# UnsupportedOperationException while removing elements from list

Tags: java, list

I have two strings having comma separated values, say one having numbers from 1 to 10 and another having prime numbers. I want to

> remove prime numbers from numbers

.

Here's my code snippet:

```
String numbers = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10";
String prime = "2,3,5,7";

List<String> numList = Arrays.asList(numbers.split(","));
numList.removeAll(Arrays.asList(prime.split(",")));
```

I'm getting UnsupportedOperationException. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to use this:-

```
List<String> numList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(numbers.split(",")));
```

If you look at the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#removeAll%28java.util.Collection%29):-

> UnsupportedOperationException - if the removeAll operation is not
>   supported by this list

`Arrays.asList` returns a fixed-size list, and hence, you get the `UnsupportedOperationException` when you try to perform the `remove` operation on that.